# How to correctly upload files to DevOps using logic app?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to upload files from incoming e-mails to DevOps using the logic app's connector "HTTP request to Azure DevOps", to than attach them to a Work Item.
The flow works, but the files I attach results in base64 encoded form if I upload them in base64, and messed up binaries if I upload them in binary format.
Anyway, them are unusable.

Is there a way to correctly upload files to DevOps?
(docx, xlsx, pdf, images, and so on?)

I tried to upload files in base64 form and binary form with "HTTP request to Azure DevOps" but I can't get the file content correctly after the upload.

I'm expecting to download the correct file from the url property outputted from "HTTP request to Azure DevOps".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved putting

```
"Body": "@{binary(body('Get_Attachment_(V2)')?['contentBytes'])}"
```

as body :-)

The function to use is actually binary() and not base64().
however "Body is Base64" has to be set to true.